# How to put a object in a linked list?

Tags: java, class, linked-list

I'm trying to make a bank record and trying to use linked list. I made my bank class and I'm trying to put that as an object in my main class and print the output. So If I enter James as a first name, black as my last name and 200 as balance. It should print the output: FirstName: James, Lastname: Black, Balance: 200. If I add another first,last, balance. It should print the new record with the old record.

```
Example:
First name      Lastname     Balance
James            Shown        4000
Kyle             Waffle       2000
```

Bank Class:

```
public class Customer2 {
    String Firstname,Lastname;
    public int balance, amount;
    int total=0;
    int total2=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public Customer2(String n, String l, int b){
    Firstname=n;
    Lastname=l;
    balance=b;
}
    public void withdraw(int amount){
        total=balance-amount;
        balance=total;

    }
    public void deposit(int amount){
        total=balance+amount;
        balance=total;
    }
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("FirstName: "+" Lastname: "+" Balance");
        System.out.println(Firstname+"         "+Lastname+"      " +balance);
    }
```

Main class:

```
LinkedList<Customer2> list = new LinkedList<Customer2>();
list.add("Bob");
list.getfirst("Lastname");
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How would I put my bank class in my linked list as an object.

Comment: you need to create a new customer2 object and add that to your linked list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new customer2 Object and then add that to your linked list

It would look like this:
Main Class:

```
Customer2 customer = new Customer2("Bob", "Doe", 1000);
list.add(customer);
```

Bob would now be added to the linked list.

If you wanted to retrieve bob from the linked list you could iterate through the list until you found bob and then call display on that object.

Or you could use getFirst (if bob is the first in the list)

that would look like this:

```
list.getFirst().display();
```

There are other methods in the linked list class that you can use to add or get if you know the position. Here is a link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedlist_class.htm

also I think this is what you wanted your display() method to be:

```
public void display(){
System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName + ", Last Name: " + lastName + ", Balance: " + balance);
```

you should also use lower case letters to start variable names as it is good naming convention aka. Firstname becomes firstname.

Comment: Thanks that made so much sense. The problem I'm having is if I add another person to the list and print it. It doesn't skip a line like it should.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put element in `LinkedList<Customer2> list` you need use method `list.add(customer)` where `customer` is object from class `Customer2`.

Comment: Could you do an example.

Answer (score -1):

```
LinkedList<Customer2> list = new LinkedList<Customer2>();
Customer2 c = new Customer2("firstName","lastName",1000);
list.add(c);
System.out.println(list);
```

Override toString() in Customer2 Class:

```
 @Override
   public String toString(){
      return "FirstName: "+fristName+",lastName: "+lastName,+"balance" +balance;
   }

//toString()
//returns string for the object
```

to print all the objects in list, each Customer2 object in a new line

```
for(Customer2 c : list){
   System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped out a low

Comment: So If I add another person to the list. It doesn't skip to a new line